# Intro JS for multiple components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intro.js

My react page has multiple components (navigation bar, image slider, popular list, etc..), so each component has separate files. so how can I use Intro JS for those components? I put all the steps in the navigation bar, but it only works for the navigation bar steps, then I put steps separately for each component, then the only one component gets worked. I used [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/o2A4gwXE3?hidenavigation=1) example for each component in my web.

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: @evolutionxbox documentation didn't mention about how to use with components

Comment: Please can you share your code in your question so we can help.